# Game Running in desktop but not running in my wpf application..why?

Tags: c#, wpf, process, game-engine

The fifa12 and blur game runs successfully by clicking the icon in desktop, but while running via my WPF application the same game.exe runs but when I start my game: quick race, online, or LAN game it loads and never starts.

I am using the below code to execute the game.exe:

```
proc.UseShellExecute = false;
string direct= new System.IO.FileInfo(@"" + txtLocation.Text + "").Directory.ToString();
proc.WorkingDirectory=direct;
proc.FileName = @"" + txtLocation.Text + "";
proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.Verb = "runas";
proc.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p1.StartInfo = proc;
p1.Start();
```

What is wrong with the code above?

Comment: Do you get any errors, if not try adding a try catch block around it

Comment: no sir I am not getting errors...

Comment: Have you tried to remove proc.CreateNoWindow = true;?

Answer (score -1):

Try only this first

```
string path = "c:\yourgame.exe";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```